# gsutil config -e giving strange error message

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

I have previously set up gsutil and Boto on this machine to use with Google Cloud Storage. I am getting a strange exception when I try to run `gsutil config -e` from the command prompt.

```
CommandException: Service account authentication requires either
PyOpenSSL or PyCrypto 2.6 or later. Please install either of these
to proceed, or configure a different type of credentials.
```

Both PyOpenSSL and PyCrypto are installed and have worked before, and I haven't seen this question asked before. Uninstalling/reinstalling boto and gsutil did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you successfully import openssl from a python interpreter on the machine by running "from OpenSSL import crypto"?  The check is a result of HAS_CRYTPO being true here https://github.com/gsutil-mirrors/google-api-python-client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py#L43 so ensure that you can execute those successfully.  Reinstalling google-api-python-client may also be worth trying.